# JSON returning null and order changes

Tags: vb.net, json, wcf

I had a WCF that returned first-name and last-name. It has been working well. I then modified the service to return one more piece of data. It returns null in that field. Also, the ordering seems to be messed up. The newly inserted field is inserted in-between the first and the last name. So now it returns:

```
  "firstname": "John",
  "fullname": null,
  "lastname": "Doe",
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON Objects does not have an order for the keys, never count on a specific order.

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects do not implement ordering, and you should never rely on it: it's not part of the specification.

As to why 'fullname' is returning as null (assuming that's unexpected), that would seem to probably depend on the particulars of the service/implementation; you haven't presented enough information to decipher anything related to that.

Comment: i just changed my sql as: Select intstudentID, nvcStudentFirstName, nvcStudentLastName, nvcStudentFullName from tblStudent where intLocationID=" & LocationID.ToString

Comment: conn.Open()

            Dim cmdStr As String = [String].Format("Select intstudentID, nvcStudentFirstName, nvcStudentLastName, nvcStudentFullName from tblStudent where intLocationID=" & LocationID.ToString)

Comment: I'll assume you do actually have a nvcStudentFullName column in your db or else you'd throw a SQL error, but what's stored in it? If you're getting nulls returned and you know there's actually data there it's one thing, but if there's not actually data present in that column then that's the correct result. You may want to modify your question with further related details if you need an answer to that.